# UWP MediaPlayer stops playing sounds

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

I'm using the MediaPlayer class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/media-playback) to play sounds in my UWP Project. This all works fine at the beginning but suddenly the Play() call starts "playing" the sound (e.g. the state of the PlaybackSession is "Playing") but there is no sound output...

```
 Dictionary<string, MediaPlayer> Effects = new Dictionary<string, MediaPlayer>();

 public async Task LoadEffects()
    {
        Effects?.Clear();
        StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("sounds");
        foreach (var effect in await folder.GetFilesAsync())
        {
            MediaPlayer snd = new MediaPlayer();
            snd.AutoPlay = false;
            snd.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(effect);
            snd.RealTimePlayback = true;
            snd.AudioCategory = MediaPlayerAudioCategory.GameMedia;
            Effects.Add(effect.DisplayName, snd);
        }
        IsLoaded = true;
    }
 public void StartPlaying(string name, float volume = 1.0f, bool force = false)
    {
      lock (_instance)
        {
            if (Effects.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                   //if force is true, force the sound to stop and play again otherwise just exit
                    if (Effects[name].PlaybackSession.PlaybackState == MediaPlaybackState.Playing && !force)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    Effects[name].Pause();
                    Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith((res) =>
                    {
                        Effects[name].Volume = volume;
                        Effects[name].PlaybackSession.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
                        Effects[name].IsLoopingEnabled = true;
                        Effects[name].Play();
                    });
            }
        }
}

public void StopPlaying(string name)
    {
        lock (_instance)
        {
            try
            {
               //if nothing is playing just return
                if (Effects[name].PlaybackSession.PlaybackState != MediaPlaybackState.Playing) return;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //weird error happens sometimes, catch it and just return
                return;
            }
            if (Effects.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Stopping {name} now; state before: {Effects[name].PlaybackSession.PlaybackState.ToString()}");
                Effects[name].IsLoopingEnabled = false;
                Effects[name].Pause();

                Effects[name].PlaybackSession.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
        }
    }
```

I noticed that it seems to happen more frequently when I'm not using the Task.Delay().
The lock is used, since I have a singleton class.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? You code snippet is not enough to reproduce your issue. What is the `force` using here?  Is this code snippet for re-playing the media? Stop playing the sound, how the frames?

Comment: I added the functions for loading and stopping the sound. Hope that is now enough to reproduce... One thing to note: it does not always happen. Only after like 4-5 times of stopping and replaying. Another thing is, the sound file is rather short.